# Do I have to use minimum 14/2awg with single appliance application

Tags: electrical, wiring

I need to run 120v from furnace control board 1amp fused to air quality sensor about 50' in crawlspace (residential).  Manual only says to comply with local and federal codes.  The sensor draws .25amps@120v hardwired 2 screw lugs only 120v and Neut. no ground

Question:  Can I use smaller gauge wire then 14/2 romex

Comment: The answer is almost certainly 'no', but do you have an example of the wire you'd like to use instead?

Comment: Can you post model of sensor? If you have a link to installation instructions that would be better.

Comment: The only way this would work is implied by NoSparksPlease's question - if the instructions (which are part of the testing lab approval) say you can use smaller wire, that supersedes the general code rule, because "following the instructions" is a specific part of wiring to code.

Comment: Further to above comments, key is also that the wire is 1A fused at the supply (the furnace). Readers should not think that just any device using well below 15A can be wired with less than 14gauge. Also, please specify whether this wire is running through floor/wall space, or free. This matters for the wire's fire rating.

Comment: Lacking specific installation instructions the general answer would likely be that you would need to use a wiring type *Listed* for the voltage, and for location used. I don't think NM cable is available for sizes smaller than #14, so you would  need to select a wire type from table 310.4(A), which would need to be installed in conduit.

Comment: There are “communications/ instruments” cables in 16 & 18 gauge and as allowed by 240.4.D if your cable is listed (usually 300v) , 18 awg requires 7amp protection with a max continuous load of 5.6 amp. , most sensors are 24v to get by the premises wiring issues but code states you have to use the manufacturers instructions (NEC 110.3.B). if the mfg states 14 you have no option, if the line is protected by a fuse (most common on systems I have installed). Note that you usually can not have a standard receptacle. Any junctions still require boxes if 120v. This and Smurf tube work great.

Comment: what's the motivation for wanting to do so?  Trying to save money? use hobby/hookup wire you already have?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.